# A complex integral that is killing me softly!

Tags: integration

I have a very complex integral as follows (believe it or not, this is it, research ended up on solving this)

$$I(\gamma,s)  = \int_{\gamma}^{\infty}  [ \frac{sv^{-1}}{1+ s\,  \,v^{-1}}]\, \lambda(v)\, dv $$
$$\lambda(v)= A\,\text{exp}(-a v^{1/2})+ B v^{-1/2}(1-\text{exp}(-bv^{1/4}))$$

with $A,a,B,b,\gamma,$ are positive constants.

I have tried everything numerical integration, symbolic integration, etc.. nothing works, so I thought maybe there could be some smart trick to simplify it before actually implmenting it in software.

I used numerical integration in MATLAB, problem is notice that $I$ has lower limit $\gamma$ and has also $z$ in the denominator, when using MATLAB I have to assign numerical values of these, the problem is I can't do that for my application since I will further have to integrate $I$ over $\gamma, z$ later on.

Any ideas to simplify it, approximate it, or is it simply impossible to handle.

Appreciate anything

Comment: «Some integrals are simply too complex to handle?» since you don't tell us much about what you are after, it is impossible to tell! As ypu surely know, some integrals cannot be solved in elementary terms, andnare used to *define* new functions.

Comment: What do you mean, I didnt tell you much, I think I have explained the problem very well, I am after solving it  @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: @Tyrone you should write out $s = 2\pi jz$. By conjugation you can write the second portion as $$\int_{\gamma}^\infty \left(\frac{v^2}{v^2 + 4\pi^2 z^2} - j\frac{2\pi z}{v^2 + 4\pi^2 z^2}\right)\lambda(v)\, dv$$

Comment: No, you have not explained nothing very well. I don't know what you are after; for example, I have no idea what you mean when you say that numerical integration doesn't work. What does «solving it» mean?! It apparently includes both finding a symbolic expression and also a numerical approximation....

Comment: OK I meant that when I plug this in a software and try to numerically evaluate it, it takes forever and it is actually the bottleneck of my problem, so I am looking for a simplification to ease the numerical computations or maybe an approxmation. @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: If you plan to further integrate, it will probably be a good idea to tell us how. it may well be the case that this integral can't be handled easily but that a double integral containing it can (by interchanging the order of the integrals and what not...)

Comment: I see your point let me add few more details !@MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: ... and f is what?

Comment: Well, it should be the obvious that a symbolic expression is hopeless... Asymtotics for I should not be difficult to get, but then you plan to use it as an exponent and with a factor that you say is too difficult. I don't know what you expect, really :-)

Comment: As i said I want to find an approximation of $I$ note that if I was note there, using complex analyis of integration I can solve the triple integral easily.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, is there a way to maybe give an approximation of I or maybe an average value?

Comment: The system flagged this thread for a large number of comments. I deleted the ones that had been read by the recipient and acted upon.

Comment: And another system flag for the large number of edits. If you have problems formulating the question to your satisfaction, you should use [the sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/11619) created with this particular kind of difficulties in mind, and then copy/paste the final form here. Multiple edits are frowned upon as they "bump" the question to the front page. Many feel that the practice is an unfair way of "hogging front page real estate", so over the year a tacit norm has emerged, and we don't like it. As a relative newcomer you probably didn't know this. No harm done. FYI!

Comment: Sure, I think I will no longer edit it. @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @JJacquelin you posted an answer then you deleted it was it incorrect? I was happy for moment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a first step leading to a closed form. But it involves Exponential Integral functions in the complex range. More work should be necessary to go to a simpler closed form (The arduous calculus at the infinite limit is possible but not completed).

[image]

[ The typos are corrected ]

Comment: @JJacquelinm thanks, in the first rectangle, why do you have $v^{-1/2}$ in the numerator of the integrand? Is that a typo?

Comment: Also I think in the second and third integral you are missing g an $s$ in the numerator (I think)? i.e I think it should be $(Bs)$ instead of $B$. But the solution is very elegant !

Comment: Hi Tyrone ! At first sight I cannot see the typo. Presently I have not time to check more carefully. If there is a mistake, please, correct it. My aim was mainly to sketch the method of solving. All the best with your work.

Comment: Thanks ! I appreciate it @JJacquelin

Comment: @Tyrone : You are right, there is an $s$ missing in the factor of the second and third integral in equation 3. This doesn't change the next part of my answer. I cannot understand your remark about $v^{-1/2}$ "in the numerator of the integrand" (where ? in what equation ?). $v^{-1/2}$ comes from the main equation stated in the wording of your question.

Comment: in the first integral that you have in the rectangle, I think there shouldn't be any $v^{-1/2}$

Comment: Ho yes ! A typo again. By the way, did you finish the solving ?

Comment: Thanks @JJacquelin your answer was very helpful !